# Converting generic linear problems into their dual

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

I'm revising how to do dual problems in linear algebra. I'm very weak in Linear programing but I struggle to cope with the topic during lectures and assignements.

I have to convert the following generic linear program to their duals

> $$(P1)=\begin{cases}\max & c^Tx\\
> &Ax=b\\
> &x\ge 0
> \end{cases},(P2)=\begin{cases}\max
>  & c^Tx\\
> &Ax=b
> \end{cases}$$
>
> $$(P3)=\begin{cases}\min & b^Tx\\
> &Ax\le b\\
> &x\ge 0
> \end{cases},(P4)=\begin{cases}\min
>  & c^Tx\\
> &Ax\le b
> \end{cases}$$

I did:

$$(D1)=\begin{cases}\min & b^Ty\\
&A^{T}y\le c\\
&y\ge 0
\end{cases},(D2)=\begin{cases}\min
 & b^Ty\\
&A^{T}y=c
\end{cases}$$

$$(D3)=\begin{cases}\max & c^Ty\\
&A^{T}y\le c\\
&y\ge 0
\end{cases},(D4)=\begin{cases}\max
 & b^Ty\\
&A^{T}y= c\\&y\le 0
\end{cases}$$

Yet, following the following array:

[image: Array of Duality rules]

Should I do:

$$(D1)=\begin{cases}\min & b^Ty\\
&A^{-1}y\le c\\
\end{cases},(D2)=\begin{cases}\min
 & b^Ty\\
&A^{-1}y=c
\end{cases}$$

$$(D3)=\begin{cases}\max & b^Ty\\
&A^{-1}y\le c\\
&y\le 0
\end{cases},(D4)=\begin{cases}\max
 & b^Ty\\
&A^{-1}y\le c
\end{cases}$$

Which are yet to be transformed into their canonical form?

Comment: For one thing, all the  $A^{-1}$ should be  $A^T $.

Comment: @Théophile isn't it the same?

Comment: No, they are very different! $A^{-1}$ is the [inverse](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html) while $A^T$ is the [transpose](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Transpose.html). The inverse is a matrix such that $AA^{-1} = I$; note that in almost all linear programming problems, the inverse doesn't exist because it is only defined when $A$ is square. On the other hand, the transpose is the result of exchanging the rows and columns of the matrix.

Comment: @Théophile Yes, okay! Understood! I mixed things up because to know if a program is feasible we have to see if its matrix is invertible...

Comment: I see. But perhaps you are checking whether something like the *basis matrix* (your terminology or approach might be different) is invertible? Again, $A$ itself will rarely be square (and therefore won't have an inverse).

Comment: @Théophile ho, you mean $A_b$, yes, it is! By the way I fixed $D_4$

Comment: Good work! (Are you sure about the objective function, though?)

Comment: @Théophile wooops! No I am!

Comment: @Théophile Should I remove the **should I do part** now? Which seems relatively wrong?

Comment: No, it's fine to leave questions as is, even if there are mistakes. Fixing mistakes can actually make it hard for other people to see why answers were written in a particular way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all four cases, your $A^{-1}$ should be $A^T$. (Make sure you understand the difference!) Apart from that, $(D1)$ and $(D2)$ are fine.

For $(D3)$, since the primal is a minimization problem with the restriction $A \mathbf x \leq \mathbf b$ (as opposed to $A \mathbf x \geq \mathbf b$), then the dual should have its variables constrained by $\mathbf x \leq \mathbf 0$ (not $\mathbf x \geq \mathbf 0$). Also, the objective function should be $\mathbf b^T \mathbf y$, not $\mathbf c^T \mathbf y$.

Can you fix $(D4)$ yourself?